# Add version to pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, version, pipeline, snakemake

Is there any standard or recommended way to add a version number to a pipeline (written in snakemake in my case)?

For example, I have this [pipeline](https://github.com/glaParaBio/genomeAnnotationPipeline) and just now I added a `CHANGELOG.md` file with the current version on top. Are there better ways to identify the version a user is deploying?

Answer (score 6):

There is a [`version` directive](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/writing_snakefiles.html#grammar), but I've never seen it used in practice:

```py
# Snakefile
version: "1.2.3"

rule all:
   input: 'test.txt'

rule test:
   output: temp(touch('test.txt'))
```

There is [an example/test for CWL conversion](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/5349f2a428ea2da511d64271fc15b65e5615b1c2/tests/test_convert_to_cwl/Snakefile) that uses `version` inside rule definition, where perhaps it might be useful, but otherwise the utility of including explicit version inside Snakefile is not clear.